# Understanding the return value of the Fibonacci Sequence in Python 3

Tags: python

Please explain how the output value of:

```
def f(x):
   if x == 0:
      return 0
   return x + f(x -1)

f(3)
```

is 6.

Comment: It's summing the numbers to zero: 3+2+1 = 6

Answer (score 3):

Let's depict how do your recursive calls look like:

```py
f(3) = 3 + f(2)
           f(2) = 2 + f(1)
                      f(1) = 1 + f(0)
                                 f(0) = 0
```

Now, let's poll the call stack from the top to down, starting with the base case (last) call:

- f(0) = 0
- f(1) = 1 + f(0) = 1 + 0 = 1
- f(2) = 2 + f(1) = 2 + 1 = 3
- f(3) = 3 + f(2) = 3 + 3 = 6.

So, the final value returned by `f(3)` is `6`.

Note, that each *f*(n) call is pushed on top of the stack, until recursion hits the base case `n==0`, from which, calls are unwound from top to down.